# Create a list of months between two dates in Access using vba code

Tags: vba, ms-access

How to Create a list of months between two dates in Access, actually I am creating a real estate management database in which agreement are made for 5/9 years with rent escalated every year by 5%

I have tables of Landlords and agreement, but i am confused how to create monthwise rent table from the agreement where start & end date is given

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail - sample input tables, and expected output table.

Comment: Hello braX, My Agreement table contains ID, Location, Landlord Name, Agreement start date, Agreement End Date, Rent, Rent Escalation after every 1or 3 years, Escalation in %- this is my Input table... And expect an output that rent for every month to be displayed in subform/subreport